# Soap API call in Objective c

Tags: ios, objective-c, soap

- API details are:

1.***GetPaymentModeData - To get available payment options.***
 
Request Parameters:
* OrderId
* LoyaltyRequestId
* MemberId

Response Parameters:
* ErrDesc - "0" as sucessful else error message
* PaymentModeList - List of all available payment options.

2.***PaymentCheckoutProcess - Process payment***
 
Request Parameters:
* OrderId
* UserEmail
* UserMobileNo
* CardNumber
* GrossAmount

Response Parameters:
* OrderId
* PaymentTransId
* ErrDesc

URL : http://mobile.cinemaxxtheater.com/WebService/Schedule.svc

Can't send parameters using this url. How it will work. I never used this kind of API call before. Please help.

Comment: where is your code?

Comment: Your question is for soap using objective c but you shared url of VB & c# code. Not able to understand your actual question. If you want to implement soap using post method you can use this link 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28373194/soap-client-generator-for-objective-c-from-wsdl